# Por que Python no ejecuta mi funcion de google app script?

Tags: python-3.x, google-apps-script

El problema que tengo es que he creado una funcion en Python para ejecutar una funcion creda en google app script. El problema es que siempre me da el mismo error y la cuestión es que la id del app script esta bien puesta y las credenciales las he utilizado miles de veces y son correctas.
El error que me devuelve es este

> An error occurred: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/1JD_cKX0Q0lKzxBTKeWhELU0WDfkN4y50I0cBEtlgmONs64Y2YyGOSUmY:run?alt=json returned "Requested entity was not found.". Details: "Requested entity was not found.">

He leido, que en algunos casos hay que vincular la cuenta de facturacion. El problema es que no soy empresa y lo hago por amor al arte y la verdad no quiero que me cobren nada por esto.

Os dejo la funcion de python para ver si alguien me puede echar una mano. Gracias.

```
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

def execute_ga_script_function():
    script_id = '1JD_cKX0Q0lKzxBTKeWhELU0WDfkN4y50I0cBEtlgmONs64Y2YyGOSUmY'
    function_name = 'myFunction'
    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

    service_account_file = 'C:/Users/xxxxx/Documents/PYTHON/xxxxxxx.json'
    creds = Credentials.from_service_account_file(service_account_file, scopes=scopes)

    service = build('script', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    request = {
        'function': function_name,
        'devMode': True
    }

    try:
        response = service.scripts().run(scriptId=script_id, body=request).execute()
        print(response)
    except HttpError as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error}")


execute_ga_script_function()
```

Comment: Hola Hector, la dirección que estás pasando no existe, entiendo que el valor de **script_id** debe ser erróneo.

Comment: No que va. Ya lo he probado varias veces. Entiendo que la id es la que viene en la url que es una barbaridad de numeros y letras y esta entre dos barras ladeadas y no es la url entera. Si estoy en lo cierto, lo he probado ya muchas veces y esta correcta porque hago un copia pega

Comment: Maestro, HttpError 404 = ruta incorrecta, dale click al enlace que te pone, y verás que no lleva a ningún lugar, tal vez no sea el id, pero en algún lugar, la ruta está mal, no es que lo diga yo, te lo está diciendo el programa.

Comment: Lo se , le he probado, pero es que por mas que miro no doy con la solucion, por eso estoy preguntando, para ver si alguien me ilumina. El archivo de google app script lo tengo compartido en modo editor con la cuenta de servicio con sus credenciales, la id es la correcta, la api de app script la tengo habilitada y ademas pilla las credenciales que tengo creadas. Ya no se por donde tirar porque no se me ocurren mas cosas.

Comment: Por eso decía lo de vincular la cuenta de facturación que era lo único que me quedaba, pero por lo que he entendido en todo lo que he leído por internet para lo que quiero hacer no es necesario. Un autentico callejón sin salida.

Comment: Voy a dar esta informacion por si sirve de algo. La url que me genera la funcion de python para conectar con mi google app script es esta: https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/1JD_cKX0Q0lKzxBTKeWhELU0WDfkN4y50I0cBEtlgmONs64Y2YyGOSUmY:run?alt=json. Y la url que tiene mi proyecto de google app script es esta: https://script.google.com/home/projects/1JD_cKX0Q0lKzxBTKeWhELU0WDfkN4y50I0cBEtlgmONs64Y2YyGOSUmY

Answer (score 1):

Héctor,

Me he encontrado con el mismo problema que tú: Quiero publicar una script e implementarla como ejecutable de API para luego poder llamarla, por ejemplo, desde rest a través de https://scripts.googleapis.com/v1 ... etc.. Después de dar varias pasadas por la documentación, Google deja claro que eso sólo se puede hacer desde un proyecto Cloud standard porque los proyectos predeterminados para Apps Scripts no son suficientes. :(

Más info: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute?hl=es-419

Comment: Gracias por la info. Al final lo hice todo desde Python.